# How to include PEAR packages by only including the PEAR.php file?

Tags: php, include, pear, mdb2

I'm using PEAR on a hosted website and I want to use the MDB2 package.
Every site on the web initializes the MDB2 package with an `require('MDB2.php')`.
Sadly, my web host only provides to me the location of the main `PEAR.php` file.

But I think I remember a method of including PEAR packages without specifically including them by file name, but using the global `PEAR` class by calling some static function.
Sadly I ran through the documentation several times and tried to Google every combination of keywords that could help me find the solution but I didn't find it. 
So, **is this possible??** And if so, **how do I do so??**

Thanks a lot, I've been looking for multiple hours now :(

Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to load pear packages through the PEAR class.

The only official way to include a pear package is to `require`/`include` the file you want to use:

```
require_once 'MDB2.php';
```

Also, your web host probably will not have MDB2 installed, so you need to ship it yourself. See the [installation on a shared host](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php) manual.